# TypeError: PyQt4.QtCore.QVariantAnimation represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4, qvariantanimation

I have this PyQt5 snippet that I'm trying to convert into PyQt4. The PyQt5 version works great but when I try to convert into PyQt4, I get this error. I removed `QtWidgets` but I still receive this error. I also tried to just instantiate `self.animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()` but still get the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test1.py", line 29, in <module>
    lineedit = LineEdit()
  File ".\test1.py", line 13, in __init__
    valueChanged=self.on_color_change,
TypeError: PyQt4.QtCore.QVariantAnimation represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated
```

Working PyQt5 version

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__()
        self.textChanged.connect(self.start_animation)

        self.animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            startValue=QtGui.QColor(255, 127, 127),
            endValue=QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255),
            duration=1000,
            valueChanged=self.on_color_change,
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start_animation(self):
        if self.animation.state() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Running:
            self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QVariant)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def on_color_change(self, color):
        self.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{background-color: %s}" % (color.name(),))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    lineedit = LineEdit()
    lineedit.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Broken PyQt4 version

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__()
        self.textChanged.connect(self.start_animation)

        self.animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            startValue=QtGui.QColor(255, 127, 127),
            endValue=QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255),
            duration=1000,
            valueChanged=self.on_color_change,
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start_animation(self):
        if self.animation.state() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Running:
            self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QVariant)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def on_color_change(self, color):
        self.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{background-color: %s}" % (color.name(),))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    lineedit = LineEdit()
    lineedit.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt4 updateCurrentValue() is a pure virtual method that needs to be implemented, in the case of Qt5 it is changing to be only a virtual method, in the first case C++ forces to implement it but with the change of Qt5 it is no longer necessary, so the solution is implement that method:

```py
# ...
class VariantAnimation(QtCore.QVariantAnimation):
    def updateCurrentValue(self, value):
        pass


class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__()
        self.textChanged.connect(self.start_animation)

        self.animation = VariantAnimation(
            startValue=QtGui.QColor(255, 127, 127),
            endValue=QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255),
            duration=1000,
            valueChanged=self.on_color_change,
        )

    # ...

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QVariant)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def on_color_change(self, color):
        if isinstance(color, QtCore.QVariant):
            color = QtGui.QColor(color)
        self.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{background-color: %s}" % (color.name(),))
    # ...
```

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, that fixed the error but now I'm getting `AttributeError: 'QVariant' object has no attribute "name"` in the `on_color_change` function

Comment: @coffeewin python2 or python3?

Comment: I'm using Python2.7

Comment: @coffeewin see my update. You have to put the information of your environment, since PyQt behaves differently for each version of Python due to the same limitations of python and the SIP version.

Comment: wow you're awesome! Is it normal for the QLineEdit to be initially red? How can I change that to be initially white?